# Typescript relative types in interface

Tags: typescript

I have an interface, like this:

```js
type DataType = "string" | "number" | "boolean" | "timestamp";
interface Schema {
  name?: string
  ...
  columns: {
    [column: string]: {
      type: DataType
      ...
      foreignKey?: {
        schema: Schema
        ...
        join: {from: string, to: string}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I have several schemas defined based on this interface, like these for example:

```js
const schemaA: Schema = {
  name: 'entity_A',
  columns: {
    col_A1: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    col_A2: {
      type: 'number'
    },
    col_A3: {
      type: 'boolean'
    },
  }
}

const schemaB: Schema = {
  name: 'entity_B',
  columns: {
    col_B1: {
      type: 'timestamp'
    },
    col_B2: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    col_B3: {
      type: 'string'
    },
  }
}

const schemaC: Schema = {
  name: 'entity_C',
  columns: {
    col_C1: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    col_C2: {
      type: 'string',
      foreignKey: {
        schema: schemaA,
        join: {from: 'col_C1', to: 'col_A1'}
      }
    },
  }
}
```

As you can see, in the `schemaC.col_C2.foreignKey`, I've passed the `schemaA` as the schema. The intention is fairly obvious, I am trying to define a related data model.

My problem is how to type-check the `join`. Specifically, I want the `join.from` to be constrained to the columns of its parent schema (here `schemaC`) and the `join.to` to be constrained to the columns of the provided schema (here `schemaA`). But as far as I understand, in order to do this, I need to be able to access some kind of `this` argument, to tell the typescript something like:

```js
join: {from: keys of this.columns}    // (the join.to is even more complicated)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAVc0C8UBEBnYAnASwDsBzTKAHyyIFcBbAIwj3KswYHsOAbCOI1lmAE6EXHDphMAbgCwAKAXFgzAGZwAxtADKGgBYQ6cKAG8FUC1CISIAfgBcUXIVJz5lqAHpPUAHT-zSw0eeiJsRzN3D0sAbWDuUMdnYhIAXQjA6OjQSEd4RBRINyys7z8AqJLLVQ48CAISIgBpCBAHU0yq6Ox9QzhHXQMjYq7Sn39fTtGLACsOYgioVTwOOiT8FOkoYA51lxIoAF8R0eOpyzPKo7dDhQVgsOAnXqMAQQGX4wxIj2tRR0wECIwlAAH1XpgADSdeKhcIdK4eeLggCMGURJRyEAByVIUPOFkO0IxFmRrwATOjpttUADaIxmPiSUdiVUyQBmKnTLEAzg8PgCVklImdEXyS73DiPZ5DOAAIQ+sqg306f2xWCBIJAoLlTKRIToYS5WWRcrRCOpPKEIjEiEkeuFQpNPB1lIt3NpWFxZCd0TFbJdcs57tGVpwGzxvo8-ouxIl8geuBlfQAwoq+sqQ1YbADNQQwSmHaSDUas-ruKCU+afh7cl6Iz6CSym8iU26a6HPeH9kWujU6g1mq1jdTk0Ykp9XlHpnMFqYlis1lhWyiodtdsuXa9V83mdHp4TfWLjkA)

So, What can I do? Is this even possible?

Am I wrong to think this should be possible? It seems pretty useful.

Comment: I'm confused by the specific join you've described. You've put the join on `col_C2`, but the `from` is `col_C1` and the `to` is `col_A1`. How is `col_C2` involved?

Comment: (It matters because it relates to possible solutions.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think `col_C2` is storing the foreign key to schema A. Of course, I could be blabbering complete nonsense; it's been a while since I worked with relational databases.

Comment: There's no specific type that works this way, but you could maybe write a generic constraint.  Like shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mLyMbW).  Does that approach meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?  (If you reply please mention @jcalz to notify me)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder although this is just a simplified example and the names are meaningless, but `col_C2` could be an alias. In a real use case, the `col_C2` could be something like `product`, and the `col_C1` would be `productId`, table A would be `products` and `col_A1` would be `productId`

Comment: @jcalz yes, it seems this is what I need. But I don't quite understand it. Can you write up an answer and explain it in more details? thank you
*************
[after some digging through your code]:
It needs some changes to fit my case, but generally it is correct. If you write your answer I will edit and then accept it. Thank you again

Comment: What edit are you planning to make? Could you first edit the question so that it contains information about the use case that would motivate whatever change you want to make to my solution?

Comment: @jcalz I was wrong. Although I don't quite understand your code, and it "seems" wrong, but it works, and my attempts to make it look "right" failed. So please post your answer and explain your logic in more detail

Comment: Okay I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no *specific* type `Schema` that meets your needs, since the valid `from` and `to` properties depend on the keys of `columns` of both the current object and that of the `schema` property.  This needs to be represented as a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type like `Schema<T>` where `T` is the type of the data you're representing.  Ideally you'd like `Schema` to mean "`Schema<T>` for *some* `T` I don't care about", but expressing that directly would require *existentially quantified generics* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14446](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466).  Instead of worrying about trying to emulate that, we can instead define generic `Schema<T>` and then write a helper function that infers `T` from a particular schema object value, so you don't have to write it out yourself.

Here's one approach:

```
type Schema<T> = {
    name?: string;
    // ...
    columns: { [K in keyof T]: {
        type: DataType;
        // ...
        foreignKey?: {
            schema: Schema<T[K]>;
            // ...
            join: { from: keyof T; to: keyof T[K] };
        };
    } };
};
```

Here we're saying that the `columns` property of a `Schema<T>` contains a property corresponding to each property of `T`; it's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over every key type `K` in the keys of `T`.  This property contains a `type` property, as well as an optional `foreignKey` property which contains a `Schema` object.  Since it presumably represents a `Schema` object for that property type, which is `T[K]`, then it is of type `Schema<T[K]>`.  Finally, the `join.from` property must be chosen from the set of keys of `T`, while the `join.to` property must be chosen from the set of keys of `T[K]`.

Then the helper function looks like

```
const asSchema = <T,>(schema: Schema<T>) => schema;
```

It's just a generic identity function that returns its input.  But you use it so that instead of writing `const foo: Schema<SomeComplicatedThing> = {...}`, you write `const foo = asSchema({...})` and let the compiler infer `SomeComplicatedThing` if it can.

---

Let's test it out:

```
const schemaA = asSchema({
    name: "entity_A",
    columns: {
        col_A1: {
            type: "string",
        },
        col_A2: {
            type: "number",
        },
        col_A3: {
            type: "boolean",
        },
    },
});
/* const schemaA: Schema<{
    col_A1: unknown;
    col_A2: unknown;
    col_A3: unknown;
}> */
```

Here, `schemaA` is inferred as type `Schema<{col_A1: unknown; col_A2: unknown; col_A3: unknown}>`.  This type is sufficient for your purposes, at least with respect to the example.  It might be *nice* if it were `Schema<{col_A1: string, col_A2: number, col_A3: boolean}>`, but you didn't care much about the value types before so it's out of scope for the question as asked.  In some sense we really only want to track key types and not full object types, but it's convenient to have an object type here even with `unknown` properties because it will let us represent the recursive types you care about whereas key-sets alone won't.

More tests:

```
const schemaC = asSchema({
    name: "entity_C",
    columns: {
        col_C1: {
            type: "string",
        },
        col_C2: {
            type: "string",
            foreignKey: {
                schema: schemaA,
                join: { from: "col_C1", to: "col_A1" },
            },
        },
    },
});
/* const schemaC: Schema<{
    col_C1: unknown;
    col_C2: {
        col_A1: unknown;
        col_A2: unknown;
        col_A3: unknown;
    };
}> */
```

Again, this is a reasonable inference.  The type of the `col_C2` property is now more specific than just `unknown`, and corresponds to the type parameter in the schema for `schemaA`.

And if we make a mistake, we'll be alerted to it:

```
const schemaCOops = asSchema({
    name: "entity_C",
    columns: {
        col_C1: {
            type: "string",
        },
        col_C2: {
            type: "string",
            foreignKey: {
                schema: schemaA,
                join: { from: "col_C1", to: "col_B2" }, // error!
                // -------------------> ~~
                // Type '"col_B2"' is not assignable to 
                // type '"col_A1" | "col_A2" | "col_A3"'
            },
        },
    },
});
```

which is the whole point of this exercise.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAVc0C8UBEBnYAnASwDsBzTKAHyyIFcBbAIwj3KswYHsOAbCOI1lmAE6EXHDphMAbgCwAKAWhIUAMoBjABYQ6cADxIAfFAwBvBVEtQiEiAH4AXFFyFSc+VagB6L1AB0ARZW6jz0RNhOplAA2gDSUMRQANYQIBwAZlBIALqRQZ6WyhBO8IgokO4FVj7+gR5VUOkceBAEJESxqY5Q5vUNVthaOnBOGtq6BnHZhpX91b4BfvlzAFYcxJGNeBx0TilpmUjSUMAce6kZWVNQAL6zVXfLN7fuj4ryIeHAUHDYY8MmKAGAA0hgAFINxiM1EMJkYAJQmYyQ4buBSfXDOWFwACCgN+-10YN6nhsoicmAgRGEoAA+jjMMDliFuGEIj1lp4WfSAIx5PpzIoUlzEMhMgWeG7i-rcnEAJn5cysQuo9CYLGlDSlnOCPHpAGZFUqTqgKZweHwBJqHtbbuKbvD3F4AFRQDHfFG6HGjbF6Em67i8pw0IhJIgcADuRHubr18uDofDUZjssNUBDYcj0YUN2Mzq8CnRHC+WKhACF8X9scTlmTilgqTSQLSy4zmaE6OEjVVuWW+RyJQ0VZhhKJxJI24PLNqp7HA2WFQPjSbIML8KLJ-0ZzK9WW0-6lcORaRN1rbTOHU7Xe7S8Myz6oX72-P+xmk9mBb3F2+synd2mf2THM8wLd4b09OAAGFK0JOAawFOsKUbAg6Ug09LBZNluwKblIP7A9BVNLBjzFHVp1tLk9UgxcCP6I91xPCiGiaFo2g6VJsOXCCnAgnEmKVNYNh6LYdgpXCeUZE4ziwWUJLtMiCm3M8nntR0FBdWMSwgyCH2GJ9Pyo19E1-Z9aWoziAyDdNjKA2dZW-GyPx3QMcQAxyYzeXMoHzQswOLTFtIAeQ4MBsBg6sCMQhtqRQ5s0NtTDO3ZWjLLwiyqno1xSNnJSeyomiFM8TKN34goWNadpOhAdK5m428vVK-pBKITZ0m2XYZMMyTTjE3c5XIKVvF8ZhtjwABCQqGhqABaWa5vmhb5uMAA-ZbJqqGpymgAByTAv0wbaEjC8Nvl+bA2LgBheCklcdr2uM5LYezBHulz9QO9b5Jy89VPcIA)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The part that I didn't understand (and still don't) is that in the generic type, why you wrote `columns: {[K in keyof T]: ...}`? the valid values for `columns` should be `[K in keyof T['columns']`. The same question arises also in `foreignKey.schema`, and `join`

Comment: `T` is the type of the underlying data you're describing with a schema object, not the type of the schema object itself.  In your `schemaA` case above, `T` is conceptually `{col_A1: string, col_A2: number, col_A3: boolean}`.  It has no `columns` property.  Does that clear it up?

Comment: But how does that happen? Where in your code, do you specify this? For example, if I had two lists of columns under the schema (eg. `columns1`, and `columns2`), how would you have specified which one you mean?

Comment: When you call `asSchema()` the compiler uses the fact that the keys of `columns` are `keyof T` to infer the keys of `T`.  Then it checks `from` against `keyof T`.  Similar things could be said for `to`.  I don't know what to say about `columns1` and `columns2`; presumably the definition of `Schema` would need to get more complicated and include possibly multiple type parameters, and `columns1` would be written `{[K in keyof T]: ...` while `columns2` would be written `{[K in keyof U]: ...`.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see where your confusion is, and we might be at an impasse because there are only so many ways I know how to phrase this.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway for your answer. It solved my problem. But I may still need to dig more to fully comprehend it.